# Create custom component in Plant3D with Python

Tags: python

Hello Stackoverflowers,

i try to create an Custom Component in Python. So far so good normally..

I know how to implement the Standard Subroutines from varmain.zip, but now i will use my own subroutine. Thats my main Function...

```html
import BOLT
from aqa.math import *
from varmain.primitiv import *
from varmain.custom import *

@activate(Group="Support", TooltipShort="Schelle mit Mutter und Basis", TooltipLong="Schelle mit Mutter und Basis", LengthUnit="mm", Ports="1")
@group("MainDimensions")
@param(D=LENGTH, TooltipLong="Innendurchmesser der Rohrhalterung(AD des Rohres)")
@param(L=LENGTH, TooltipLong="Laenge der Schelle")
@param(W=LENGTH, TooltipLong="Staerke der Schelle")
@param(K=LENGTH, TooltipLong="Gesamtbreite der Schelle")
@param(SW1=LENGTH, TooltipLong="Schluesselweite")
@param(K1=LENGTH, TooltipLong="Kopfhoehe Schraube")
@param(E1=LENGTH, TooltipLong="Eckmass")
@param(L1=LENGTH, TooltipLong="Laenge Schraube")
@param(D1=LENGTH, TooltipLong="Durchmesser Schraube")

def SUP1 (s, D=116.0, L=30.0, W=4.0, K=0.0, SW1=18.0, K1=7.5, E1=20.0, L1=40.0, D1=12.0, **kw):
        R1 = D/2.0
        R2 = R1 + W
        if K <= 0.0:
           K = D + L * 2.0
        o1 = CYLINDER(s, R=R2, H=L, O=0.0).translate((0, 0, -(L / 2.0)))
        o2 = BOX(s, L=K, W=L, H=W * 3.0)
        o3 = CYLINDER(s, R=R1, H=L, O=0.0).translate((0, 0, -(L / 2.0)))
        o4 = BOX(s, L=K, W=L, H=W)
        o5 = BOLT(s, SW=SW1, K=K1, E=E1, L=L1, D=D1)
        o1.uniteWith(o2)
        o2.erase()
        o3.uniteWith(o4)
        o4.erase()
        o1.subtractFrom(o3)
        o3.erase()
        o1.rotateY(90)
        s.setPoint((0, 0, 0), (-1, 0, 0))
```

And this is the subroutine BOLT

```html
import math
import aqa.math
from aqa.math import *
from varmain.primitiv import *
from varmain.custom import *

@activate(Group="Support", TooltipShort="Schraube DIN 931", TooltipLong="Schraube DIN 931", LengthUnit="mm", Ports="1")
@group("MainDimensions")
@param(SW=LENGTH, TooltipLong="Schluesselweite")
@param(K=LENGTH, TooltipLong="Kopfhoehe")
@param(E=LENGTH, TooltipLong="Eckmass")
@param(L=LENGTH, TooltipLong="Gesamtlaenge")
@param(D=LENGTH, TooltipLong="Schraubendurchmesser")

def BOLT (s, SW = 18.0, K=7.5, E=20.0, L=40.0, D=12.0, **kw):
        if K <= 0.0:
           K = SW/2
        KWdt = SW * math.tan(aqa.math.asRadiants(30.0))
        o1a = BOX(s, L=SW, W=KWdt, H=K).translate((K/2,0.0,0.0))
        o1b = BOX(s, L=SW, W=KWdt, H=K).rotateX(60.0).translate((K/2,0.0,0.0))
        o1c = BOX(s, L=SW, W=KWdt, H=K).rotateX(-60.0).translate((K/2,0.0,0.0))
        o2 = CYLINDER(s, R=D/2.0 ,H = L - K, O = 0.0).rotateY(90).translate((K, 0.0,0.0))   
        o1a.uniteWith(o1b)
        o1b.erase()
        o1a.uniteWith(o1c)
        o1c.erase()
        o1a.uniteWith(o2)
        o2.erase()
```

The Subroutine works fine standalone, but when i will run (testacpscript "SUP1") in Plant, Console told me "Script SUP1 not found..."
When i comment out the line "o5 = BOLT(s, SW=SW1, K=K1, E=E1, L=L1, D=D1)" and "import BOLT" anything works fine.

Any ideas whats going wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solved my Problem, had to add the Path.

```html
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.normpath(sys.PnP3dNativeContentCustomScriptsPath))
```